# Different database name in SELECT and connectionURL, does this matter?

Tags: mysql

We have a custom Java code that connects to MySQL (8.0.23-14). Developers are using one database connection to trigger several queries, not too much parallel load though. But for the JDBCConnection the URL they have is `jdbc:mysql://HOST:3306/DBNAME` whereas the SELECT queries are run on different databases as well using the same connection object (like `FROM DBNAME1.Tablename`, `FROM DBNAME2.TableName2` and so on). We just get the responses fine, but when I noticed the processes on MySQL Server, I see them getting created on the main database being used in the initial connection obviously. Does this impact performance of database(s)/query responses in any way? Is it advised instead to use different Connection objects for different database specific queries so that the databases used SELECT should match always with the one used in the connection? In that scenario, how to handle queries with multiple databases?
Please advise.

Comment: The first thing that came to mind was that old adage _"If it aint broke, dont fix it"_

Comment: :) Thanks @RiggsFolly. But I just don't want one database being overburdened and impacted if this is really so. Also rarely we see Communication Link Failure error within 2 minutes window exactly, I am sure this is nothing to do with the database and its variables, but something going wrong on the driver/client connection side, so worried on this.

Comment: Remember, all databases exists under the single instance of MySQL the DBMS. The fact that the instance is looking at 2 databases is fairly academic

Comment: @BillKarwin While you are there, am I right about this one?

Comment: so this means, the process being shown against a database (in the output of SHOW PROCESSLIST) doesn't really mater at all? In other words, even if all the running query processes are with just one database, it won't impact/overburden that database or the actual target database on which the query is triggered at all in terms of any additional connection/data transfer like that?

Comment: As for "parallel load"; let's look into optimizing the queries.  Speeding up the queries is the most likely way to decrease "parallel load".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
USE db1;    -- or whatever is specified by the "connection"
SELECT ... FROM db2.tbl ...;
```

`db2` rules in the execution of the query.  `db1` in the `PROCESSLIST` is just misleading.  No "impact".

Do you have any evidence to the contrary?

Maybe, *only maybe*, there is some obscure case where the collation of a Stored Procedure, the collation of the connection, and the collation of the table being accessed don't align.  If so, you should probably make all of them consistent, regardless of `DATABASE`.

The main purpose of `USE` is to specify which `DATABASE` to use when it is not otherwise stated (as in `FROM db2.tbl`).  Databases are primarily a simplistic tool for organizing one's `TABLEs` and Stored Procedures and a few other things.

It is quite OK to connect to one db, then modify tables in other dbs.  The one thing to watch for is `GRANT` permissions to the various dbs.  For security reasons, it is generally *not* wise to `GRANT ALL ON *.*` to anyone other than the admin.  It is OK to `GRANT` one user to full (or partial) access to a subset of the Databases; this seems to be your case.